# How to close a side menu (plugin) by clicking anywhere on the body?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, menu, hide, show-hide

I have this plugin that I downloaded from http://www.berriart.com/sidr/ once I click on a button it shows slides the menu and when I want to close it I can only close it by clicking back on the same button. Now I want to add a click anywhere in the body to move back the menu. could anyone please help me fix this?

Here is my html:

```
<div id="sidr">
<!-- <button class="close-side-menu"><i class="icon-close"></i></button> -->
<ul>
<li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<button type="button" class="menu-icon open-side-menu">
<a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">
</a>
</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#simple-menu').sidr();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this script:

```
    $(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var container = $("#sidr");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {


        $.sidr('close', 'sidr');

    }
});
```

Managed to get a script from this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it) then was able to add `$.sidr('close', 'sidr');`just make sure to change the 'sidr' to the class name of the menu you'd like to try.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should work for your purposes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != 'simple-menu') && !$(this).parents('#simple-menu').length) {
              $.sidr('close', 'simple-menu');
        }
    });
});
```

This checks the onclick event fired from clicking the body and verifies that you did not click on the menu or an ancestor of the menu

Comment: Thanks for helping out. still not working, it says: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover 
any thoughts ?

Comment: Neither the code you posted nor the code I posted makes use of :hover so either the problem is somewhere else in your code or in the library itself. Can you reproduce this issue in jsfidde or do you have a live site you can direct me to?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue in jsfidde but I couldnt since I have many files and im still working locally so I have no link to the site I'm working on. Would it be helpful if you take a look a the actual plugin from http://www.berriart.com/sidr/ ? the one I am using called "simple menue"

Comment: There is nothing in the plugin using the :hover psuedoclass. Check your code and see if you are using anywhere. Are you using any other javascript libraries?

Comment: This works for me except for the extra close parens after 'simple-menu'.  The if statement should be: `if ($(this).attr('id') != 'simple-menu' && !$(this).parents('#simple-menu').length)`